# LibGDX Sprite Not Rotating With Both "Rotate" and "setRotation"

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am currently creating a game based on a platform that tilts side to side and there is a ball on that platform. For this ball I applied dynamic body physics and got it to work great, but when I try updating the ball's sprite rotation based on the ball's body angle the sprite will not rotate.

My code is below.

```
public static void update(float delta) {

    delta *= 0.7;
    world.step(delta, 10, 4);

    //Angular Impulse is here to test if ball sprite is rotating
    ballBody.applyAngularImpulse(40, true);
    AssetManager.ballSprite.setRotation(ballBody.getAngle());
    AssetManager.ballSprite.setPosition(ballBody.getPosition().x,
            ballBody.getPosition().y);

    }

}
```

Comment: How are you drawing the `ballSprite`?

Comment: Yeah the error was with how I was drawing it I was using batch.draw(sprite) instead of sprite.draw(batch).

Comment: could you put that as an "answer" below to this question?  It will make it easier for folks in the future that run into similar issues.  Thanks!  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to rotate a sprite in libgdx when rendering it you must do:

```
sprite.draw(spritebatch);
```

but I made the mistake of trying to render it how I would render anything else:

```
spritebatch.draw(sprite);
```